# Vortex motion equation for flux-flow instability

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, performance-tuning

I am solving the motion equation of an isolated vortex oscillation in a superconductor. I am assuming that the driving force is generated by an RF current oscillating at 1.3 GHz.
The main point of this calculation is to see what's the effect of flux-flow instability under RF drive.
The code I wrote is reported below.

```
f = 1.3 10^9; (*Hz*)
\[Omega] = 2. Pi f;
Trf = 1./f;

Tc = 9.25; (*K*)
T = 1.5; (*K*)

\[Mu]0 = 4. Pi 10^-7; (*H/m*)
\[Phi]0 = 2.07 10^-15; (*Wb*)
n = 5.56 10^28; (*m^-3*)
e = 1.6 10^-19; (*C*)
m = 9.1 10^-31; (*kg*)

\[Tau] = 0.5 10^-9; (*s*)
vf = 1.37 10^6; (*m/s*)
Bc2 = 410. 10^-3; (*T*)
l = 100 10^-9; (*m*)
\[Lambda] = 49.5 10^-9; (*m*)
\[Xi] = 28 10^-9; (*m*)
\[Kappa] = \[Lambda]/\[Xi];

\[Gamma] = (\[Phi]0)/(\[Mu]0 \[Lambda] );

v0 = Sqrt[(l vf Sqrt[14 Zeta[3] (1 - T/Tc)])/(3 Pi \[Tau])];

\[Rho] = (m vf)/(n e^2 l);
\[Eta] = (\[Phi]0 Bc2)/\[Rho];

g = Log[\[Kappa]]+0.5+Exp[-0.4-0.8 Log[\[Kappa]]-0.1(Log[\[Kappa]])^2]; 
\[Epsilon] = (\[Phi]0^2 g)/(4. Pi \[Mu]0 \[Lambda]^2);

Tmax = 3. Trf;
Zmax = 1. 10^-6; (*m*)

B = 100. 10^-3; (*T*)

sol = NDSolve[{
     (v0^2 \[Eta])/(v0^2 + D[x[t, z], t]^2)D[x[t, z],t] == \[Epsilon] D[x[t, z], z, z] + \[Gamma] B Cos[\[Omega] t] Exp[-(z/\[Lambda])],
     x[0., z] == 0.,
     x[t, Zmax] == 0.,
     (D[x[t, z], z] /. z -> 0) == 0.
     }, x, {t, 0., Tmax}, {z, 0., Zmax},
    AccuracyGoal -> 13,
    PrecisionGoal -> 2,
    MaxSteps -> Infinity];
u[t_, z_] = Evaluate[x[t, z] /. sol][[1]];
du[t_, z_] = D[u[t, z],t];

phaseSpace = 
   ParallelTable[{Re[u[t, 0.]] 10^6, Re[du[t, 0.]] 10^-3}, {t, Trf, 
     Tmax, Tmax/500.}];
ListPlot[phaseSpace, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

I am able to get a almost correct result out of this calculation only if I fix the solution domain to 1 micron (Zmax = 1. 10^-6). This is however not correct because the vortex should be able to oscillate more than that inside the bulk, therefore I am literally chopping my solution using a too small domain.

If I fix Zmax to a larger number (e.g. 5 um) I need to fix MaxStepSize to a small number in order to avoid errors and the calculation would take more than 2 days on my PC (I actually stopped it after 2 days because the PC froze up!). Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Also, I was wondering if there is any way to solve the equation when the vortex velocity is higher than v0 (the velocity onset for flux-flow instability). If I fix B to let's say 200 mT, then the vortex velocity would be larger than v0 and the calculation does not return a correct solution, just a series of spikes. Is there any Method I can use to solve this problem?

Please let me know!
Thank you in advance.

Mattia

Comment: I posted an answer, but it is probably a numerical artifact.  I noticed that all of your BCs and ICs are zero.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. In the bulk the vortex do not move and it is perpendicular to the surface. However, the initial condition might be set differently I believe. The best condition would be to put the IC for a vortex with zero velocity, but I do not know the analytical form of it, that's why I put zero as IC (static vortex). I figured that if the solution is calculated for a large enough number of oscillations, it converges to a steady state solution anyway.

Answer (score 5):

When working with small spatial and temporal scales, it is often conducive to scale the variables by characteristic lengths and times (or reciprocal frequencies).  The natural choices for length is $\lambda$ and reciprocal time is $\omega$.  If we create dimensionless $x$, $z$, and $t$, and do the appropriate substitutions, we should be able to derive a dimensionless differential equation that depends on several dimensionless groups.

My non-dimensionalized version of your dimensioned equation is

$$\frac{{\frac{{\partial x}}{{\partial t}}}}{{{\nu ^2}{{\left( {\frac{{\partial x}}{{\partial t}}} \right)}^2} + 1}} = \delta \left( {\rho \frac{{{\partial ^2}x}}{{\partial {z^2}}} + Cos(t)Exp( - z)} \right)$$

If we use your initial parameters:

```
f = 1.3 10^9;(*Hz*)ω = 2. Pi f;
Trf = 1./f;

Tc = 9.25;(*K*)
T = 1.5;(*K*)
μ0 = 4. Pi 10^-7;(*H/m*)
ϕ0 = 2.07 10^-15;(*Wb*)
n = 5.56 10^28;(*m^-3*)
e = 1.6 10^-19;(*C*)
m = 9.1 10^-31;(*kg*)
τ = 0.5 10^-9;(*s*)
vf = 1.37 10^6;(*m/s*)
Bc2 = 410. 10^-3;(*T*)
l = 100 10^-9;(*m*)
λ = 49.5 10^-9;(*m*)
ξ = 28 10^-9;(*m*)
κ = λ/ξ;

γ = (ϕ0)/(μ0 λ);

v0 = Sqrt[(l vf Sqrt[14 Zeta[3] (1 - T/Tc)])/(3 Pi τ)];

ρ = (m vf)/(n e^2 l);
η = (ϕ0 Bc2)/ρ;

g = Log[κ] + 0.5 + 
   Exp[-0.4 - 0.8 Log[κ] - 0.1 (Log[κ])^2];
ϵ = (ϕ0^2 g)/(4. Pi μ0 λ^2);

Tmax = 3. Trf;
Zmax = 1. 10^-6;(*m*)
B = 100. 10^-3(*T*)
```

Here is my modified non-dimensionalized version of your code.

```
Zmax = 100;
Tmax = 20;
vc = λ ω;
nu = vc/v0;
rho = ϵ/(λ B γ);
delta = (B γ)/(η vc);
sol = NDSolve[{D[x[t, z], t]/(1 + nu^2 D[x[t, z], t]^2) == 
     delta ( rho D[x[t, z], z, z] + Cos[ t] Exp[-z]), x[0., z] == 0., 
    x[t, Zmax] == 0., (D[x[t, z], z] /. z -> 0) == 0.}, 
   x, {t, 0., Tmax}, {z, 0., Zmax}];
u[t_, z_] = Evaluate[x[t, z] /. sol][[1]];
du[t_, z_] = D[u[t, z], t];
phaseSpace = 
  Table[{Re[u[t, 0.]] , Re[du[t, 0.]] }, {t, Trf ω, Tmax, 
    Tmax/500.}];
ListPlot[phaseSpace, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Phase plot]

It took about 2.5 seconds to run on my machine.  I won't have time to double check my work for a couple days, but I hope this gets you started.

Comment: I received two messages:  `NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 2.888363945453023`*^-45.`
`NDSolve::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 576279.2946597305` at t = 2.888363945453023`*^-45 in the direction of independent variable z is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. `

Comment: You are correct.  I did not hear the beeps last night, but I hear them now and I see the same message.   More investigation is needed.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I noticed that all the BCs and ICs are zero, which seems like it would be difficult/impossible to evolve.  I'll ask the OP for additional guidance.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to make everything dimensionless, I believe it helped a lot on speeding up the calculation. I get the same error Alex Trounev get, but the code still spits out the solution.

Answer (score 2):

A small code change allows you to solve both problems. Figure 1 shows solutions for increasing `B` and `Zmax`.

```
f = 
 1.3 10^9;(*Hz*)\[Omega] = 2. Pi f;
Trf = 1./f;

Tc = 9.25;(*K*)T = 1.5;(*K*)\[Mu]0 = 4. Pi 10^-7;(*H/m*)\[Phi]0 = 
 2.07 10^-15;(*Wb*)n = 5.56 10^28;(*m^-3*)e = 1.6 10^-19;(*C*)m = 
 9.1 10^-31;(*kg*)\[Tau] = 0.5 10^-9;(*s*)vf = 1.37 10^6;(*m/s*)Bc2 = 
 410. 10^-3;(*T*)l = 100 10^-9;(*m*)\[Lambda] = 
 49.5 10^-9;(*m*)\[Xi] = 28 10^-9;(*m*)\[Kappa] = \[Lambda]/\[Xi];

\[Gamma] = (\[Phi]0)/(\[Mu]0 \[Lambda]);

v0 = Sqrt[(l vf Sqrt[14 Zeta[3] (1 - T/Tc)])/(3 Pi \[Tau])];

\[Rho] = (m vf)/(n e^2 l);
\[Eta] = (\[Phi]0 Bc2)/\[Rho];

g = Log[\[Kappa]] + 0.5 + 
   Exp[-0.4 - 0.8 Log[\[Kappa]] - 0.1 (Log[\[Kappa]])^2];
\[Epsilon] = (\[Phi]0^2 g)/(4. Pi \[Mu]0 \[Lambda]^2);

Tmax = 3. Trf;
Zmax = 5. 10^-6;(*m*)B = 300. 10^-3;(*T*)sol = 
 NDSolveValue[{ \[Eta]/(1 + D[x[t, z], t]^2/v0^2) D[x[t, z], 
       t] == \[Epsilon] D[x[t, z], z, 
        z] + \[Gamma] B Cos[\[Omega] t] Exp[-(z/\[Lambda])], 
    x[0., z] == 0., 
    x[t, Zmax] == 0., (D[x[t, z], z] /. z -> 0) == 
     0.}, {Re[x[t, 0]]*10^6, Re[D[x[t, 0], t]]*10^-3}, {t, 0., 
    Tmax}, {z, 0., Zmax}, AccuracyGoal -> 13, PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity] // Quiet;


phaseSpace = ParallelTable[sol, {t, Trf, Tmax, Tmax/500.}];
ListPlot[phaseSpace, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> Grid[{{"Zmax = ", Zmax}, {"B = ", B}}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you Alex. There is something strange in the solutions you get, as a function of B both speed (y-axis) and displacement (x-axis) should increase as a function of the rf field amplitude B. I noticed as well that if Zmax is increased (keeping the same B) the code tends to return a solution that qualitatively is ok (an ellipse) but it is not accurate and generally underestimated. To partially solve this I used the "SingleStep" method specifying MaxStepSize and StartingStepSize. The solution in this way is more accurate when Zmax is increased.

Comment: I meant "FixedStep", sorry

Comment: @Mattia OK! You probably understand what the solution should be. I just indicated how to choose a branch of solution using ` NDSolveValue` instead of ` NDSolve`.